# How can I get this tricky sum of a Hadamard product of generating functions?

Tags: analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

I am interested in the sum of a Hadamard product of generating functions.

If we are given $n$ functions, where $0 < i \leq n$, of the form:

$$f_i(x_i) = \sum_{j=0}^m{c_{i,j} x_i^j}.$$

The hadamard product is defined as:

$$g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^m{( \prod_{i=0}^n {c_{i,j}})x^j}.$$

It's essentially the same as going through all the generating functions simultaneously and multiplying all the $j$th coefficients together to obtain a new coefficient.

> Some given information

I have polynomials; I think of them as finite length generating functions.  I know that all of the coefficients are natural numbers.  I'd like the sum of the resulting coefficients.

There's a trick.  Calculating the Hadamard product generates an extremely complicated expression.  I would like to avoid dealing with this expression explicitly, if possible.

I want to know ways that I could do this.

Comment: *What* has a finite length? The power series of a rational function does not terminate; only polynomials have terminating power series expansions.

Comment: An additional note:  Differentiation and integration may prove tricky because I'm working with extremely large powers of x.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry - I have a polynomials - they're incomplete "generating functions". I'd still like to sum the (product of coefficients)

Comment: I have read through many of your questions on this project and I still have no idea what it is you want to do.  What format do you have your sequences stored as?  What is it about this format that makes a direct computation difficult?  Why don't you switch formats?

Comment: I'm playing around with NP complete problems.  I'm experimenting with numerical techniques to see if I can come up with competitive methods this way.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to come up with better formats and formulations.

Comment: So specifically you have the following expression: $c_{0,0}*c_{1,0}*...*c_{n,0} \space + \space c_{0,1}*...*c_{n,1} \space + ... + \space c_{0,m} * ... * c_{n,m}$ and you would like to evaluate it with fewer than $(m+1)n$ multiplies and $m$ adds?

Comment: Don't know if this will help but, the Hadamard product of two rational functions is rational (Theorem 2.4 of "Lectures on Generating Functions" by S. K. Lando, AMS publication stml-23).